# Inverting a function without rewriting it in Python

Tags: function, python-3.x

I have a string function (and I am sure it is reversible, so no need to test this), could I call it in reverse to perform the opposite operation?

For example:

```
def sample(s):
    return s[1:]+s[:1]
```

would put the first letter of a string on the end and return it.

'Output' would become 'utputO'.

When I want to get the opposite operation, could I use this same function?

'utputO' would return 'Output'.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand. Are you trying to invert arbitrary functions (because that's a math question), or invert particular string functions (which might be a python question), or wondering whether python has built-in arbitrary inversion functionality (no, not really possible)?

Comment: @en_Knight: it's the 2nd case.

Comment: Okay, that's a much better question  :) Could you clarify that in your question ("I have a function", not "if I have a function", which to me sounds way more general), and show what happens in some unit cases and what you believe the behaviour to be? I think you'll get waay better response that way.

Comment: Inversion is only possible for side-effect free injective functions. Simply create a lookup table when you execute the function and then reverse-lookup. Just kidding ;)

Comment: @nucleon hmm functions have to be bijective (i.e., surjective and injective) to be invertible. I don't see how side-effect-free implies surjective, or is there an implicit embedded condition that provides that, like finite state?

Comment: For example, a function that takes strings and maps them to real numbers injectively would not be invertible (there can't exist an "inverse function"), because the spaces don't line up

Comment: For a simpler example of why this is not possible in general, consider the inverse function of `len`

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no.

Longer answer: I can think of 3, maybe 4 ways to approach what you want -- all of which depend on how are you allowed to change your functions (possibly restricting to a sub-set of Python or mini language), train them, or run them normally with the operands you are expecting to invert later.

So, **method (1)** - would probably not reach 100% determinism, and would require training with a lot of random examples for each function: use a machine learning approach. That is cool, because it is a hot topic, this would be almost a "machine learning  hello world" to implement using one of the various frameworks existing for Python or even roll your own - just setup a neural network for string transformation, train it with a couple thousand (maybe just a few hundred) string transformations for each function you want to invert, and you should have the reverse function. I think this could be the best - at least the "least incorrect" approach - at least it will be the more generic one.

**Method(2)**: Create a mini language for string transformation with reversible operands. Write your functions using this mini language. Introspect your functions and generate the reversed ones.

May look weird, but imagine a minimal stack language that could remove an item from a position in a string, and push it on the stack, pop an item to a position on the string, and maybe perform a couple more reversible primitives you might need (say upper/lower) -

```
OPSTACK = []
language = {
    "push_op": (lambda s, pos: (OPSTACK.append(s[pos]), s[:pos] + s[pos + 1:])[1]),
    "pop_op": (lambda s, pos: s[:pos] + OPSTACK.pop() + s[pos:]),
    "push_end": (lambda s: (OPSTACK.append(s[-1]), s[:-1])[1]),
    "pop_end": lambda s: s + OPSTACK.pop(),
    "lower": lambda s: s.lower(),
    "upper": lambda s: s.upper(),
    # ...
}

# (or pip install extradict and use extradict.BijectiveDict to avoid having to write  double entries)
reverse_mapping =  {
    "push_op": "pop_op",
    "pop_op": "push_op",
    "push_end": "pop_end",
    "pop_end": "push_end",
    "lower": "upper",
    "upper": "lower"
}

def engine(text, function):
    tokens = function.split()
    while tokens:
        operator = tokens.pop(0)
        if operator.endswith("_op"):
            operand = int(tokens.pop(0))
            text = language[operator](text, operand)
        else:
            text = language[operator](text)
    return text

def inverter(function):
    inverted = []
    tokens = function.split()
    while tokens:
        operator = tokens.pop(0)
        inverted.insert(0, reverse_mapping[operator])
        if operator.endswith("_op"):
            operand = tokens.pop(0)
            inverted.insert(1, operand)
    return " ".join(inverted)
```

Example:

```
In [36]: sample = "push_op 0 pop_end"

In [37]: engine("Output", sample)
Out[37]: 'utputO'

In [38]: elpmas = inverter(sample)

In [39]: elpmas
Out[39]: 'push_end pop_op 0'

In [40]: engine("utputO", elpmas)
Out[40]: 'Output'
```

**Method 3**: If possible, it is easy to cache the input and output of each call, and just use that to operate in reverse - it could be done as a decorator in Python

```
from functools import wraps

def reverse_cache(func):
    reverse_cache = {}
    wraps(func)
    def wrapper(input_text):
        result = func(input_text)
        reverse_cache[result] = input_text
        return result
    wrapper.reverse_cache = reverse_cache
    return wrapper
```

Example:

```
In [3]: @reverse_cache
...     def sample(s):
...        return s[1:]+s[:1]

In [4]:

In [5]: sample("Output")
Out[5]: 'utputO'

In [6]: sample.reverse_cache["utputO"]
Out[6]: 'Output'
```

**Method 4**: If the string operations are limited to shuffling the string contents in a deterministic way, like in your example, (and maybe offsetting the character code values by a constant - but no other operations at all), it is possible to write a learner function without the use of neural-network programming: it would construct a string with one character of each (possibly with code-points in ascending order), pass it through the function, and note down the numeric order of the string that was output  - 
so, in your example, the  reconstructed output order would be (1,2,3,4,5,0) - given that sequence, one just have to reorder the input for the inverted function according to those indexes - which is trivial in Python:

```
def order_map(func, length):
    sample_text = "".join(chr(i) for i in range(32, 32 + length))
    result = func(sample_text)
    return [ord(char) - 32 for char in result]

def invert(func, text):
    map_ = order_map(func, len(text))
    reordered = sorted(zip(map_, text))
    return "".join(item[1] for item in reordered)
```

Example:

```
In [47]: def sample(s):
   ....:         return s[1:] + s[0]
   ....: 

In [48]: sample("Output")
Out[48]: 'utputO'

In [49]: invert(sample, "uputO")
Out[49]: 'Ouput'

In [50]:
```